# Multiple MDM server, multiple APNs certificates?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

Our company wants to develop 3rd party MDM server to support iOS platform. My question is about the APNs certificates from Apple.

We want to sell our developed MDM server, is that possible? What I could imagine is as following.
1. we enroll as enterprise developer program. Require MDM push notification certificates.
Question: Could I use only one certificate for all of my distributed MDM servers to my customers? Or I need a separate certificate for each MDM server?

2. Does this violate contrast of Enterprise developer program? If so, how could I archive this kind of stuff?

Actually, all my question is about to distribute our developed MDM server to 3rd party customers, is that possible and how? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The MDM server wouldn't be distributed via the app store or via an enterprise program - it is a server application that you distribute however you like.  Many MDM solutions have a client.  This is typically made available via the app store like any other app. e.g. You can search the app store for Meraki, Airwatch or MobileIron clients

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, Paulw11, I mean sell the MDM server to customers, could this be possible? Not via app store to distribute, I do not understand the APNS certificates part of MDM server. MDM server need APNs certificate to contact with Apple server and then push notification to devices.

Comment: Your certificate would be embedded into your MDM server. You would only need a single certificate. You would need a developer program membership in order to create an app, get it in the App Store and get a push certificate but this would just be the normal program, not the enterprise program.

Comment: Hi, Paualw11, I know about normal iOS development stuffs, but this is about apple MDM solution. There's no relationship with app store stuffs. I need to finger out the possibility of develop 3rd party MDM server (according to Apple's document, this involve develop HTTPS server conform Apple's protocols), my question is about MDM server's APNs certificate which is totally different with normal app's APNs certificate.

Comment: Ok, I understand now.  Your customers need to generate their own push certificate by submitting a CSR at https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?appIdKey=3fbfc9ad8dfedeb78be1d37f6458e72adc3160d1ad5b323a9e5c5eb2f8e7e3e2&rv=2 and install it into your MDM software.  You can create a free MDM account at https://n69.meraki.com/login/dashboard_login and see how the process works

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Paulw11, that make sense now. My understand is as the following:

1. apply one Enterprise developer account. Request to be a vendor of MDM.
2. develop the MDM server, and distribute to customers.
3. Customer generate CSR and I use vendor certificate to sign it, and then customer use the signed file (plist format) to generate push certificate on the URL you paste above.
4. customer deploy the certificate on the distributed MDM server our company developed.

Am i correct? Just one more question, if i am correct, do the customer need to enroll iOS developer program to generate the certs?

Comment: Yes - you are correct with the process. I do not believe they will need a developer portal account to get the cert generated. Not every shop is a technology/development shop.

Comment: Thanks, Dan, so only a normal apple ID(without become a developer program) from the customer is required to generate the MDM certificate is needed, correct? The customer need to do this themselves. I will do some test and put the result here. thanks again.

Comment: I believe so, yes. I can check with my Apple rep tomorrow. Given the bigger picture that Company X may have absolutely no development capabilities but wants to manage devices I find it hard to believe they'd be required to purchase a Dev acct.

Comment: Okay, thanks, Dan, I will try to do some test though I do not have an enterprise account (only have a 99$ account) and put the result here.

Comment: Yes, my progress is right. I see the progress in apple's official website. It only require the customer to register an apple ID, and verified this apple ID (it is always should be in your email, a URL link). Thanks you all for the help.